# Magento 2 Composer Update

Tags: magento2, composer

> The "https://repo.magento.com/packages.json" file could not be downloaded: SSL: Connection reset by peer
>   [image: screencapture of error]

How can I fix this?  I already updated my credentials.
This is my `~/.composer/auth.json` file

```
{
    "http-basic": {
        "repo.magento.com": {
            "username": "public_key_from_magento_0123456789",
            "password": "private_key_from_magento_012345678"
        },
        "company-i-work-for.git.beanstalkapp.com": {
            "username": "my_username",
            "password": "0123456789"
        }
    },
    "github-oauth": {
        "github.com": "863a989b657e232c7a790ad0123456789"
    }
}
```

Comment: can you provide the composer version you are using `composer -v` ?

Comment: Yes, 1.1.2 is my current version

Comment: can you see if this works for you https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/4825

Comment: No it did not work although it's an interesting issue  - I changed my php.ini file timeout to 360 instead of 60 like it mentioned.

Comment: What about this issue - https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/5519 - do you think it's my actual composer.json file configuration?

Comment: Found an article regarding this on the devdocs http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/release-notes/tech_bull_tls-repo.html#solution-macos see if this fixes the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you're on a Mac. The issue could be the fact that your openssl package either doesn't support or doesn't default to TLS 1.1+. I'm not certain but that looks like the error you would get. See if [this](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/install-gde/system-requirements_repo-tls1-2.html) helps explain it but it's up to you to find an update in your software repo or get openssl from another repo.

Comment: Also, upgraded to MAMP 4.0.4 issue is now fixed.